# Progress template in the middle of content template

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a gridview in update panel and I am doing paging in that, 
I want update progress while paging

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upGvFinishProg" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upGvFinish" DisplayAfter="0">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <center>
                        Loading ....
                        </center>
                    </ProgressTemplate>
```

But this is showing me text below of the gridview. I want this to be shown in the middle of gridview, i.e. middle of the content template of update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked about this at asp.net website..

you can use javascript to adjust this stuff..

```
//    set the progress element to this position 
        Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation(updateProgressDiv, x, y);
```

I suggest you to follow these links:

[Displaying Update progress at center of gridview](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/983/displaying-update-progress-at-center-of-gridview/)
[UPDATE PROGRESS IN THE MIDDLE OF A GRIDVIEW RSS](http://forums.asp.net/p/1247623/2297843.aspx)
[UpdateProgress is not displayed in the middle of the grv](http://forums.asp.net/p/1629688/4204911.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check this example from Raj Kaimal's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/01/08/using-the-updateprogress-control-as-a-modal-overlay.aspx)

It shows how to use the UpdateProgress control as a modal overlay, so you'll be able to place it over your grid. I think its exactly what you're looking for.

Raj has created a new AJAX extender called UpdateProgressOverlayExtender which seems to fit the requirement.